# TF30063: You are not authorized to access <VSO collection> - Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, build-process, azure-devops

While trying to configure Build Controller/Test Controller and Build Agent/Test Agent there is a problem to connect to VSO.

It is however possible to connect to VSO via Web Portal without any issue. The problem occurs while configuring Build and Test environment. Notice that the permission is not the issue !

[image: The error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be resolved after establishing the connection via Test Explorer.

After establishing the connection in Team Explorer 2013. I was able to choose the VSO collection in the build/test service configuration without experiancing the issue.

In conclusion before you configure the build/test tools install Test Explorer and establish there the connection to your VSO team collection and later in the build/test tools.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776

Comment: That should not be necessary, but I am glad that it worked for you.